# The application has Stopped Unexpectedly, Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Am trying to display Map on My device (Android). I think I have done everything right as well added permissions to the Manifest, but When executing it says that the Application has Stopped Unexpectedly. Please try again.

Manifest file details

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/> 
<permission android:name="com.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyD5oEA4Ct8_q_Ic-YBVjSv0_ANMfatvysY"/>
```

Logcat

```
05-16 20:19:43.433: W/dalvikvm(303): VFY: unable to resolve static field 872 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
05-16 20:19:43.433: D/dalvikvm(303): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
05-16 20:19:43.442: D/dalvikvm(303): VFY: dead code 0x0010-00ae in Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;.createFromAttributes (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;
05-16 20:19:43.452: D/AndroidRuntime(303): Shutting down VM
05-16 20:19:43.452: W/dalvikvm(303): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.example.mymap.Map.onCreate(Map.java:21)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-16 20:19:43.482: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 20:24:43.612: I/Process(303): Sending signal. PID: 303 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post your manifest file and layout file code?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 
 <uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>
 
 <permission
  android:name="com.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

Comment: <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="AIzaSyD5oEA4Ct8_q_Ic-YBVjSv0_ANMfatvysY"/>

Answer (score 1):

You should refer the google play services library project in your map project.

My guess you have not referred to the google play services library in your android map project

Import your library project to your worksace. import the same to eclipse.

When you import the library to eclipse. you can if its a library project

Right click on your library project. goto properties. choose android. you should see a similar window as below

[image]

Right click on your project. goto properties. Choose android. click add. browse and add the library project.

[image]

Comment: Is it not the same as downloading the google play Services in the Android SDK?

Comment: When adding the library, it is only detecting another project. In this case, Maps (which I have).. Is there a way u can add it Manually?

Comment: Import your google play services library into your eclipse. Then right click on your andorid project. goto properties. click android. click add add the library project. You can close the other map project and try. right click on the other project and click close project.

Comment: @andrewmolo for more clear information check the link and snap shots here http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: @andrewmolo your project should  also have google api as the target as shown in the above snap shot

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded the Google Lib Services as well as importing them to the Workspace.

Comment: The error is gone but its not showing the map.. Its only showing the zoom options. + and-

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your key. are you testing it on emulator. test it on a real device